# How to extract variable from the existing type in TypeScript and apply to another parameter

Tags: typescript

Having the following types:

```
// Stub for schema
type TSchema<Obj> = any

type TRoute<TSomeInbound, TSomeOutbound> = {
  url: string
  validation: {
    in: TSchema<TSomeInbound>
    out: TSchema<TSomeOutbound>
  }
}
```

and the route example:

```
type ExampleInbound = {
  userId: string
}

type ExampleOutbound = {
  greeting: string
}

const exampleRoute: TRoute<ExampleInbound, ExampleOutbound> = {
   url: '/happy',
   validation: {
      in: {
         userId: 128
      },
      out: {
         greeting: 512
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to build a `fetch()` adapter that lets me pass the route and extracts the payload type on its own from the first parameter, rather than engage me to add `<TInbound, TOutbound>` it manually.

Currently, I've got:

```
async function fetchFromApi<TInbound, TOutbound>(route: TRoute<TInbound, TOutbound>, payload: TInbound) {
   const res = await fetch(route.href)
   return res.json() as TOutbound
}

// This works fine
const result = await fetchFromApi<ExampleInbound, ExampleOutbound>(exampleRoute, {userId: 'Joe'})
```

but since those two variables (ExampleInbound, ExampleOutbound) are already supplied in the `exampleRoute` type, I am looking for a way to remove them from being hardcoded in `fetch()` so that they're extracted from `exampleRoute` in this case.

So the desired implementation shall be:

```
const result = await fetchFromApi(exampleRoute, {userId: 'Joe'})
```

Any advice or help how that might be?

Comment: Does this question depend on joi? If so, please tag it as such. If not, please [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] that doesn't rely on third-party code definitions.